# Uncaught ReferenceError: Hashem is not defined

Tags: javascript, php, mysql

Im trying to pass php variables that i retrieve from mysql database to javascript variables, first loop works just fine , second loop retrieves data but doesnt pass it to the javascript variables. Console Error Saying

"Uncaught ReferenceError: Omar is not defined "  which is the last value in my database

```
<?PHP
        include("config.php");

           $sql="SELECT * FROM  `latlong`";
            $rs = mysqli_query($con,$sql);
             $sql2="SELECT * FROM  `hashemfl`";
            $rs2 = mysqli_query($con,$sql2);
            while($array=mysqli_fetch_array($rs))
            {
                $Lat=$array['Lat'];
                $Lng=$array['Long'];
            }

            while($array2=mysqli_fetch_array($rs2))
                    {
                $User=$array2['Name'];              // Console Error is Here
                echo $User;
                    }
    ?>





    <html>

      <head>
        <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no" />
        <style type="text/css">
          html { height: 100% }
          body { height: 100%; margin: 0; padding: 0 }
          #map_canvas { height: 100% }

          #select_route {width:20%;height:200px;}
        </style>

        <script type="text/javascript"
          src="http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false">
        </script>

     <script type="text/javascript">

    var Lat=<?PHP echo $Lat?>;
    var Lng=<?PHP echo $Lng?>;
    alert(Lat);
    alert(Lng);
    var User=<?PHP echo $User?>;

    alert(User);
```

Comment: You need to quote + encode the string. Use `json_encode()` for this.

Comment: @SalmanA but the first loop works just fine , i dont understand whats causing a problem in the second loop

Comment: Assuming that the `name` column contains the value `Omar` the resulting JavaScript would look like `var User= Omar;` and this will cause the `Omar is not defined` error.